# Não existe neste contexto a variável c#

Tags: c#

Isto é erro do C#, ou estou fazendo alguma coisa errada pois na minha lógica isto deveria funcionar perfeitamente.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Banco Bbanco;
    Bbanco = new Banco();

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não pode fazer atribuições no corpo de uma classe separadas da declaração.

Isto não funciona:

```
public class Test
{
    Banco BBanco;
    BBanco = new Banco();       
}
```

Pode, no entanto, fazer a atribuição na altura da declaração:

```
public class Test2
{
    Banco BBanco = new Banco();
}
```

Ou pode fazer a atribuição dentro de um método/construtor:

```
public class Test3
{
    Banco BBanco;

    public Test3()
    {
        BBanco = new Banco();
    }
}
```

Pode consultar os exemplos [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YVtm7k).

Comment: ou dentro do construtor :)

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza editei para evitar duvidas, mas um [constructor pode ser considerado um metodo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646461/can-i-say-a-constructor-is-a-method)

Comment: Que legal, então não existe a possibilidade de fazer atribuições fora de uma classe que super interessante, muito obrigado.

Comment: @rock.ownar, na realidade é fora de um método ou construtor. fora de uma classe você estaria dentro do namespace. que também não seria possível.